# Google Sheets Apps Script, return random item from named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a custom function that I can give a name range as input and have it output a random item from the name range.  I have multiple named ranges so it would be convenient to have one function that I could use for all of them.  This is what I'm trying to replace `=INDEX(named_range,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(named_range)),1)`

This is what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
function tfunction(n) {
  var randomstuffs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(n);
  var randomstuff = randomstuffs[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomstuffs.length)];
  Logger.log(randomstuff); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this edited script:

```
function tfunction(n) {
  //randomstuffs will only get all cell data that are not empty from a named range
  var randomstuffs = [].concat.apply([], SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(n).getValues()).filter(String);
  var randomstuff = randomstuffs[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomstuffs.length)];
  return randomstuff; 
}
```

**Sample Result**

> Created a sample named range `TestRange` on Column A with 21 cells of data then tried the custom function `=tfunction("TestRange")` which returned a random cell value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`.getRangeByName()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename) returns a reference to a range, not the values in the range. You need to add `.getValues()` to it:

```
var randomstuffs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(n).getValues();
```

Also keep in mind that [`.getValues()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2D array of values, indexed by row, then by column. So your `var randomstuff` declaration will need to be change to account for that, depending on how many rows and columns your range has.

Comment: The named ranges are all single columns.
I've added .getValues() but it's still giving me errors